# What's the best way to look up why/when changes were made in a git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I am inspecting the gem Shoulda as an example. Shoulda no longer has the methods `assert_good_value`. So my question is, what is the best way to figure out when and why it was removed, and what it might have been replaced by?

So far, the only way I could think to do this is to clone the git related to Shoulda, and do :

```
git log -Sassert_good_value
```

Which brought back a few commits worth investigating. However, I'm not really sure how to investigate these commits other than `git checkout` into the SHA and see if I can see anything important. But doing so this way does not show me what was *added/removed*, and it also doesn't show me how or if any of these are connected to a git issue.

What am I possibly doing wrong, or what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: [git-blame](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html)? :)

Comment: @joachim I was gonna say the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log -p`

That gives you a `less` interface containing each commit as a `diff`. Then enter `/assert_good_value` to search for a change to it.

Answer (score 1):

To investigate the commits from doing the `git log -Sassert_good_value`, you could just `git show` into the SHA. That will return all the changes made by that certain commit.

Hope that helps!